# Better Tracking With Pythonista Scene Module

Tags: python, ios, python-module

This is my first time posting to Stack Overflow, and I’m very new to the scene module for Pythonista, so please forgive any minor mistakes, and tell me if I have any mistakes regarding the formatting/question.

I’m currently trying to create a program that allows the user to hand draw a circle, and then take the circumference. However, the look of my line depends upon the send of which I draw. For example, if I draw fast, then the dots (the line segments) are few and far between, while slowly drawing makes it much more accurate. (I do not have the circumference yet, but I figure I can put a dot down every nth distance, then use the amount of dots and calculate it from there).

The question I’m posing is, how do I make it so that when I draw, speed does not (or at least insignificantly) impacts the line?

Notes- I’ve seen examples in the examples tab on Pythonista, and they all us the UI module, but since I already know a tiny bit of Scene, I want to stick with this. If it proves to be impossible, I’ll switch. (Also, if someone wishes to, could they create a tag that is “scene-module”? Thanks.)

```
from scene import *
import math
allPoints = []
line = []
def addPoint(x, y):
    allPoints.append((x, y))

class MyScene(Scene):
    def setup(self):
        self.background_color = '#a9a9a9'
        self.followPlayer = SpriteNode('shp:Circle',    position = (-10,-10))
        self.add_child(self.followPlayer)
    def touch_began(self,touch):
        self.followPlayer.position = touch.location
    def touch_moved(self, touch):
        x, y = touch.location
        addPoint(x, y)
        self.followPlayer.position = touch.location
        self.drawNode =  SpriteNode('iob:ios7_circle_filled_24', (x, y), parent = self)

run(MyScene())
```

Thank you